# How can I remove rows from all the data frames within a list?

Tags: r

I am trying to remove the row from all the dataframes within a list. I do not know how.

The basic structure of data is all five imputed data frames in one list. 
I am trying to delete rows from those data frames if certain data frame does not satisfy the condition (for example, col3 <= 0, i.e. deleting rows with negative col3 values). In this way, I can compare all the data frames in the appropriate manner.

This has to do with the previous question:

[How can I have a subset of a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49739550/how-can-i-have-a-subset-of-a-list-of-data-frames)

---

(addition)
For example, I have the following list of data frames

```
 > temp <- list (
 data.frame(house=c(1,-3,-2), income=c(2,3,4), capital=c(3,5,6)),
 data.frame(house=c(1,-3,-2), income=c(2,3,4), capital=c(3,5,6)),
 data.frame(house=c(1,-3,NA), income=c(2,3,4),capital=c(3,5,6))
  )

> temp
[[1]]
  house income capital
1     1      2       3
2    -3      3       5
3    -2      4       6

[[2]]
  house income capital
1     1      2       3
2    -3      3       5
3    -2      4       6

[[3]]
  house income capital
1     1      2       3
2    -3      3       5
3    NA      4       6
```

Now, I want to have list without 'house < =0' 
so I want to do something like this,

```
temp <- subset(temp, house>0)
```

First, this code did not work.. I do not know why... second, the other list in my code was able to execute subset function. However, the thing is three data frames were not balanced after the change. It is due to NA in the 3rd data frames. It did not discard 3rd row from 3rd data frames, thus the whole list is not balanced.

As you can see from previous question, I am working on Survey of Consumer Finance dataset, and they have 5 imputation data frames in the list, and when I try to trim negative house value rows from whole list, it only removed only some of the data frame. I guess there are a whole public dataset as well as a extract dataset, and the latter does not include house column.....

Comment: Please give both a clear description of what you are trying to do and a [mcve]. That said -- you can use `lapply()` to map a computation over a list, including a list of dataframes.

Comment: *"I am trying to delete rows from those data frames if certain data frame does not contain the row."* This is vague and circular. Create a simple example. `my_list = list(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars)`. Now, which row do you want to delete? Is there a criterion to test, or just a particular value in a particular column? A row name? The 8th row?....

Comment: I admit my question was so poor... I tried to fill the gap this time... However, my knowledge of R interrupts me from asking a clear question... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
lapply(temp, function(x) subset(x, house > 0))
#[[1]]
#
#  house income capital
#1     1      2       3
#[[2]]
#
#  house income capital
#1     1      2       3
#[[3]]
#
#  house income capital
#1     1      2       3
```

Or the same can be achieved with

```
lapply(temp, function(x) x[x$house > 0 & !is.na(x$house), ])
```

Comment: This is really nice... That is what I wanted...Unfortunately, the code I am running is not working with this "lapply". It is using library "survey" and "mitools", and the list is multiplication imputed list... 
This is the related document...
(http://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/svymi.html)

Comment: @user9620331 `lapply` is a standard base R function. My solution is based on the sample data *you* provide. You don't mention those packages in your original post, and this makes it an entirely different question that you should ask in a separate post.

Comment: sorry about that.. I will ask then in a separate question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Or from `filter` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
temp %>% 
     map(filter, house > 0)
#[[1]]
#  house income capital
#1     1      2       3

#[[2]]
#  house income capital
#1     1      2       3

#[[3]]
#  house income capital
#1     1      2       3
```